# Replacing list values in a while loop

Tags: list, python-2.7, replace, while-loop

So I am trying to add two lists, a nominal list and a random number list, together to create a new list made up of positive values. My issue is that my list of random numbers is being generated from a normal distribution (`random.normalvariate(0, SD)`) which means occasionally I get negative values when summing the two lists, something I do not want.

I have tried to resolve this issue using a while loop to check whether the sum of the two lists at each item creates a negative value and if it does replace the random number with a new random number. However my code does not seem to be replacing the values no matter how I adjust it. Here is my current attempt.

```
nominalList = [1,2,3,4,5]
randomList = []

for n in xrange(0, len(nominalList)):
    randomList.append(random.normalvariate(0, SD))

while nominalList[n] + randomList[n] < 0:
    randomList[n] = random.normalvariate(0, SD)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the indices again and reassign any that don't meet your criteria:

```
import random
SD = 7

nominalList = [1,2,3,4,5]
randomList = [random.normalvariate(0, SD) for n in nominalList]

for i,n in enumerate(nominalList):
    while n + randomList[i] < 0:
        randomList[i] = random.normalvariate(0, SD)
```

Or another thought, just indent the `while` in your original code:

```
nominalList = [1,2,3,4,5]
randomList = []

for n in xrange(0, len(nominalList)):
    randomList.append(random.normalvariate(0, SD))

    while nominalList[n] + randomList[n] < 0:
        randomList[n] = random.normalvariate(0, SD)
```